Translating C to Zig vs C to Rust
I wrote a program in C to test a function that took 85s to run as shown below.
unsigned int sorted_stepping(double seed, unsigned int* list,
                             unsigned int max_val, unsigned int list_size) {
    unsigned int seat_number = round(seed * (max_val - list_size));

    for (int i = 0; i < list_size; ++i) {
        if (list[i] > seat_number) {
            break;
        } else {
            seat_number++;
        }
    }

    return seat_number;
}

int main() {
    unsigned int max_val = 1000;
    unsigned int list[] = {1, 3, 4, 10, 15, 25, 100, 150, 214, 999, 1000};

    double seed = 0.0;
    unsigned int random_number;

    // calling the function 1,000,000,000 times
    for (long i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i) {
        seed += 0.000000001;
        random_number = sorted_stepping(seed, list, max_val,
                                        sizeof(list) / sizeof(unsigned int));
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "Generated random number for seed %f is %d\n", seed, random_number);

    return 0;
}

When I translated it to Zig, the performance was same (took 85s) as shown below.
const std = @import("std");

pub fn sorted_stepping(seed: f64, list: []const u32, max_val: u32) u32 {
    const temp: f64 = @floatFromInt(@as(usize, max_val) - list.len);
    var seat_number: u32 = @intFromFloat(@round(seed * temp));

    for (list) |list_item| {
        if (list_item > seat_number) {
            break;
        } else {
            seat_number = seat_number + 1;
        }
    }

    return seat_number;
}

pub fn main() void {
    const max_val = 1000;
    const list = [_]u32{ 1, 3, 4, 10, 15, 25, 100, 150, 214, 999, 1000 };

    var seed: f64 = 0.0;
    var random_number: u32 = 0;

    // calling the function 1,000,000,000 times
    for (0..1_000_000_000) |_| {
        seed += 0.000000001;
        random_number = sorted_stepping(seed, &list, max_val);
    }

    std.debug.print("Generated random number for seed {} is {}\n", .{ seed, random_number });
}

But when I translated the code to Rust, the performance drop was so much that it took 250s to run (almost 3 times more time).
fn sorted_stepping(seed: f64, list: &[u64], max_val: u64, list_size: usize) -> u64 {
    let mut seat_number = (seed * (max_val - list_size as u64) as f64) as u64;

    for item in list {
        if item > &seat_number {
            break;
        } else {
            seat_number = seat_number + 1;
        }
    }

    seat_number
}

fn main() {
    let max_val: u64 = 1000;
    let list = [1, 3, 4, 10, 15, 25, 100, 150, 214, 999, 1000];

    let mut seed: f64 = 0.0;
    let mut random_number: u64 = 0;

    // calling the function 1,000,000,000 times
    let mut i: u32 = 0;
    while i < 1_000_000_000 {
        seed = seed + 0.000_000_001;
        random_number = sorted_stepping(seed, &list, max_val, list.len());
        i = i + 1;
    }

    println!("Generated random number for seed {0} is {1}", seed, random_number);
}

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong in Rust? I am very new to both Zig and Rust and Zig feels more easy to translate my existing C code than learning how Rust works internally to get the same or better performance.

How do you compile any of it? How do you time any of it? Why do you use a for in Zig and C, but a while in Rust? Why do you print to what I assume to be stderr in Zig? …

As I am new to both languages (Zig and Rust), I didn't know the syntax and just googled stuff. They all give same results but different performance. As for compilation, I just used default commands

Recursive and iterative fibonacci also give the same result but different performance, that's the point, you have to compare apples with apples, not apples with oranges like you do.

Timing was calculated by printing current time between calls in batch file (I'm running on Windows) and calculating the difference

Please [edit] your question to add all relevant information instead of answering in the comments.

@cafce25 But why does literal translations of code give different results in terms of performance

It is more difficult to tell the actual performance stuff from the source code than to take a look into the actual machine code. If you can upload the assembly listings generated by the compilers, I believe it is much more easy to see the difference. If they are too long you can post them in the pastebin and link.

@GokulRajV For this one, 'why does literal translations of code give different results in terms of performance', by taking an extreme example, when u calculate the addiction two 32bit number in C, it is usually just a ADD instruction in CPU. However, if it's in Python, there should be quite much more to do. Literal translation of source code in different languages can generate quite much different machine code.

@GokulRajV you haven't literally translated the code though, and even if you could, that can still be massively influenced by semantics and optimization.

@Limina102 I'll try to paste the machine code generated by compilers if possible. Comparing C and Python makes sense as they are different strategies of code execution (compiling to machine code versus running byte code on an interpreter). These compilers are supposed to output same optimized machine code and Zig was able to do that. But Rust on the other hand needs some learning of language to translate my code to get same or better performance.

Did you run with --release?

@ChayimFriedman No, same for other compilations as well

Benchmarking debug mode is meaningless, in any language.

I'm surprised the --release question comes so late, normally this is the very first question :D Yes, I have to agree with Chayim Friedman, benchmarking without --release is completely pointless. The amount of optimization in debug mode varies greatly from language to language, and is completely arbitrary. Rust debug mode does very little optimization, so speedups in the order of 10x are quite common when enabling --release.

I recommend -O3 for C/C++, --release for Rust/Cargo, and -O ReleaseSafe or -O ReleaseFast for Zig, depending on your usecase. Then, numbers should be comparable.

@GokulRajV I don't have Zig installed, so I can only compare C and Rust. C (clang) without optimization takes 24.4s. C with -O3 takes 11.5s. Rust without optimization takes 67.7s. Rust with --release takes 1.9s but surprisingly prints a different result: for seed 0.9999999925399329 is 997 instead of for seed 1.000000 is 998

@Finomnis Seems the floating point mechanism is different, or the process converting floating point to string when outputing

@Finomnis Thanks for the comments, this is what I was looking for. With optimization flags on, the performance increased drastically across all compilers. Rust gave the fastest executable but not sure what has been optimized internally. Regarding the results, Zig and C gave the same expected results but Rust result is one less. Must be the float point mechanism. Thank you everyone for the inputs.
